# Calling an express route by using .click not working on the phone

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works in my chrome browser but not on my phone. My code is:

```
   $('#plusSign').on('click', function() {

        var myLink = document.getElementById('plusLink')

        myLink.click();

    });
```

I can get the function to run from my from but the line myLink.click() will not do anything. Is this not an option for the phone?

I use expressJS and I am trying to call the path to one of my routes defined in app.js. I have also tried .trigger('click'), which did not work either.

Comment: check for ending semicolon for your variable declaration.

Comment: have you included jq mobile version too?

Comment: @Jai I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got from [jQuery Mobile tap documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/):

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "tap", function( event ) { ... } );
```

so you can amend your code like this:

```
$('#plusSign').on('tap touch click', function() {

    var myLink = document.getElementById('plusLink')

    myLink.bind('tap');

});
```

Comment: i get the error " object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no function 'bind' from my computer and my phone does not even call the event

Comment: and your jquery's version is? and have you tried `trigger` instead of `bind`

Comment: jquery version 1.9.1 and Yes I did try trigger as well but thank you. I have run out ideas and have not found anywhere saying this can not be done. All suggestions are much appreciated